# При создании превью из pdf создается черный фон

Tags: php, imagick

```
exec("convert -normalize \"".$patch."[0]\" -colorspace RGB -resize 300 \"/".$row['id'].".jpg\" ");
```

Как сделать фон по умолчанию белым? imagick не использую из-за ненахождения им части файлов, баг не решен официально

Answer (score 0):

## convert

Попробуйте ключ `-white-threshold value`.

Из `man`: force all pixels above the threshold into white

```
convert -white-threshold 0 -normalize -colorspace RGB file.pdf out.jpg
```

Ключ `-resize 300` я исключил, появлялись артефакты.

В целом, качество полученных картинок меня не устроило, я использую `unoconv`.

## unoconv

```
unoconv -f jpg -o out.jpg test.pdf
```

Также можно указать gif формат. Экспортируется только первая страница. Если нужны все - придется резать PDF постранично.